# VSCode's "Run Python File" button doesn't sync with default terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, cmd

I have set my default terminal as cmd in VSCode however, everytime I press "Run Python File" button on top right corner it run my python file in python shell instead of cmd(my default terminal).

I alreday searched for this issue I believe this is a bug from VSCode version 1.60
so, does this bug remain unfix yet or there is a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

note:

```
Version: 1.66.2 (user setup)
Commit: dfd34e8260c270da74b5c2d86d61aee4b6d56977
Date: 2022-04-11T07:46:01.075Z
Electron: 17.2.0
Chromium: 98.0.4758.109
Node.js: 16.13.0
V8: 9.8.177.11-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22000
```

*Edit:
[image: This is my terminal when I open my VSCode.]
This is my terminal when I open my VSCode.

[image: When I hit the "Run Python File" button as you can see my python file was not running in my default terminal(cmd).]
When I hit the "Run Python File" button as you can see my python file was not running in my default terminal(cmd).

[image: Is this what You mean by "cmd and when my python file running separately?]
Is this what You mean by "picture of your vsocde terminal when code runs and Windows CMD separately"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My vscode version is 1.66.2 the same as you.

Please ensure that the selection of default terminal is consistent with the figure below:

[image]

[image]

If this does not solve your problem, please upload your default settings for further analysis.

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir however, that doesn't solve my problem since I already have the same settings as you suggest and what do you mean by default settings? did you mean my terminal settings?

Comment: @Zeroz Could you please provide the picture of your vsocde terminal when code runs and Windows CMD separately. Because vscode is connected to the local CMD, there is no reason to directly enter the python shell without typeing in "python".

Comment: sorry for the late reply sir. I have edited my post, I hope I provide the picture as you want.

Comment: @Zeroz This terminal named "Python" 's essence is CMD. When you run the file, it will start the python specific CMD and name it "Python". From your description, I thought that the running file automatically entered the python shell which needs to enter "python" in CMD. Trust me, vscode is right and correct

Comment: You can refer to this document for more details so that you can understand my reply more clearly. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

Comment: oh I get it now sir, I really appreciate your help and explanation thanks a lot sir